# expected primary-expression before ‘*’ token

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have written a code that converts a std::string in sensor_msgs::Laserscan::constPtr structure. The code is given below:

```
std::vector<char> scan_vectr;
  boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
  std::size_t lens=tcp_socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(scan_vectr),ignored_error);
  std::string scan_str(scan_vectr.begin(),scan_vectr.end());

  //Deserialize the std::string in sensor_msgs::LaserScan structure
  std::size_t serial_size = scan_str.size();
  boost::shared_array<uint8_t> buffer(new uint8_t[serial_size]);
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < serial_size; ++i)

  {
    buffer[i] = scan_str[i];
  }
  ros::serialization::IStream stream(buffer.get(), serial_size);
  const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr scan;
  ros::serialization::Serializer<const sensor_msgs::LaserScan>::read(stream,sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr *scan);
```

In the last line of the code, I am getting this error...

```
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/serialization.h: In instantiation of ‘static void ros::serialization::Serializer<T>::read(Stream&, typename boost::call_traits<T>::reference) [with Stream = ros::serialization::IStream; T = const sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> >; typename boost::call_traits<T>::reference = const sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> >&]’:
/home/collab/catkin_ws/src/slam_gmapping/gmapping_server/src/slam_gmapping.cpp:315:82:   required from here
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/serialization.h:136:5: error: ‘const struct sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘deserialize’
     t.deserialize(stream.getData());
 ^
```

I don't know how to handle it, please someone help me to get rid of this error.
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255977/expected-primary-expression-before-%E2%80%98*%E2%80%99-token/) by [user_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/28458/user_123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a C++ problem more than anything else: you can only pass *variables* to functions, nothing else. Your current line:

```
ros::serialization::Serializer<const sensor_msgs::LaserScan>::read(stream,sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr *scan);
```

is passing `sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr *scan` to `read(..)`. `sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr *scan` is not valid C++: it's a variable declaration inside a call to a function.

If you just want to pass `scan` itself, you should remove `sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr` from that line.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [user_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/28458/user_123/) on 2017-03-02**:
After removing sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr I am getting a new set of error edited in the question. Please check and help me.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-02**:
You'll need to make sure you're passing the correct variables to the functions that you're calling. This is not ROS-specific, but basic C++. Unfortunately I won't have the time to debug your code with you.